# CPT parent page to have child pages

Tags: custom-post-type, archive

Can't find the solution to the following. My CPT has a slug which is a page. I use the following:

```
'has_archive' => false,
'rewrite' => array('slug' => '/admissions/connect', 'with_front' => true),
```

But when I add this, the /connect page can't have child pages which are not CPT.